# Why did Hank Pym say he created the formula that altered atomic relative distance only 20 years prior?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, ant-man

In *Ant-Man*, Hank Pym said this to Scott Lang:

> Twenty years ago I created a formula that altered atomic relative distance.

Well, *Ant-Man*'s events were set in 2015. 20 years before that year was 1995.

But in *Avengers: Endgame* Steve Rogers stole Pym's particles from his lab in 1970.

So why did Hank Pym say that to Scott Lang?

Comment: Hank isn't obliged to be truthful.  Obfuscating when he invented the Pym particle may be to disguise the period when he used it as a government agent.

Comment: FWIW you don’t even need Endgame to see the inconsistency here. The opening scene takes place in 1989, 26 years prior and he’d been using the formula for years at that point. Though I think iandotkelly is probably correct here; he’s just being purposefully ambiguous. Either that or he’s “rounding”.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I know that scene, I just wanted to make an older example.

Comment: Ant-Man started development in 2006.  Maybe this was a left-over line from an early draft.  That would explain the opening scene, at least, though not the later revelations in *Endgame*.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that Hank didn't yet trust Scott enough to tell him priority information. Remember that Scott was trying to make a clean streak and if Scott was to go to the authorities, they might get a little too much if that was what Hank had revealed to Scott. Also, Scott and Hank have a history of lying to each other. It could just be a plot hole, though; remember in Homecoming it said "eight years later" after the events of 2012's Battle of New York, and that was retconned by Infinity War.